# How to only display date, not time, in a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my table currently looks like:

[image]

This is the corresponding PHP code:

```
                        <?php
                            //include 'database.php';
                            $pdo2 = Database::connect();
                            $sql2 = "SELECT id,
                                    full_name,
                                    owner_name awardee,
                                    owner awardee_email,
                                    (select concat(user_name,' ',user_last_name) from users where email = who_created) awarder,
                                    creation_time
                                    FROM awards, award_types
                                    where who_created = ? and awards_type=type_id";
                            $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
                            $q2->execute(array($_COOKIE["email"]));
                            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
                            foreach ($q2 as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['full_name'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['awardee'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['awardee_email'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['awarder'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['creation_time'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td><a class="btn" href="DeleteAward.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete Award</a></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                           }
                           Database::disconnect();
                          ?>
```

I want to only display the date, not time, under the "Date" column.  I read from other posts that I need to use some sort of `date(creation_time)` or `DATE_FORMAT(creation_time)` command, but I tried both and they just make my "Date" column blank.

I suspect that I'll need to change the `echo '<td>'. $row['creation_time'] . '</td>';` line as well, but I was not able to find any guidelines on how to do so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to go about it:

The MySQL way:

```
SELECT DATE(creation_time) AS creation_time
```

Or the PHP way:

```
$creation_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['creation_time']));
```

**Edit** Here's the exact code for each way:

Mysql:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id,
    full_name,
     owner_name awardee,
     owner awardee_email,
    (select concat(user_name,' ',user_last_name) from users where email = who_created) awarder,
     DATE(creation_time) AS creation_time
     FROM awards, award_types
     where who_created = ? and awards_type=type_id";
```

And PHP version:

```
foreach ($q2 as $row) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['full_name'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['awardee'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['awardee_email'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['awarder'] . '</td>';
     $creation_time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['creation_time']));
     echo '<td>'. $creation_time . '</td>';
     echo '<td><a class="btn" href="DeleteAward.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete Award</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The MySQL way wiped out my entire table.  Where do I put the PHP way command?  Do I include it as part of my SELECT query, or should I replace it somewhere in the echo?

Comment: The MySQL way shouldn't affect your table at all, as it's only a SELECT command. The PHP way would be within your results foreach loop, then you would output `$creation_date` instead of `$row['creation_time']`.

Comment: I tried that but it's making my entire "Date" column blank again.

Comment: I'll update my answer with the exact way to do both.

Comment: The `$creation_time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['creation_time']));` did the trick.  Thank you!